# Would be glad if anyone could handle this error code, couldn't find what's wrong

Tags: java, debugging

My program gets an hour & minutes of start time and end time every day for 30 days of a worker, then finds the longest day he works at and sets it as the output to display. The problem (I think) seems to be in the for loop, here is the loop part:

```
for (ti=1; ti<=3; ti++) {

            System.out.println("Please enter the hours and minutes you started by this order.");
            double hours1 = reader.nextDouble();
            double mins1 = reader.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("Please type the time you finished in hours and minutes by this order.");
            double hours2 = reader.nextDouble();
            double mins2 = reader.nextDouble();

            double total = difference(hours1, mins1, hours2, mins2);

            tdays.add(total);

            if (tdays.get(ti) > tdays.get(ti - 1)) {
                big = tdays.get(ti);
                tday = ti;
            }

        }
```

Error code:

```
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:373)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:425)
    at Main.main(Main.java:24)
```

Full code: ```import java.util.*;
public class Main {

```
static Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Double> tdays = new ArrayList<>();
    int ti, tday=0;
    double big=0;
    for (ti=1; ti<=3; ti++) {

        System.out.println("Please enter the hours and minutes you started by this order.");
        double hours1 = reader.nextDouble();
        double mins1 = reader.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Please type the time you finished in hours and minutes by this order.");
        double hours2 = reader.nextDouble();
        double mins2 = reader.nextDouble();

        double total = difference(hours1, mins1, hours2, mins2);

        tdays.add(total);

        if (tdays.get(ti) > tdays.get(ti - 1)) {
            big = tdays.get(ti);
            tday = ti;
        }

    }

    System.out.println("The worker has worked " + big + " hours on day number " + tday + ".");

}

public static double convertMin (double hours, double minutes) {

    double totalmin;
    hours = hours * 60;
    totalmin = hours + minutes;

    return totalmin;

}

public static double difference(double mins1, double hours1, double mins2, double hours2) {

    double total1 = convertMin(hours1, mins1);
    double total2 = convertMin(hours2, mins2);

    return total2 - total1;

}
```

}

```
Thanks for any help!
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you add only one element to the list, but then you try to access index "1" (which would be the second element)

I think you can fix this by adding a check if `tdays.size() > 1` (or something like that)

I've separated the lines to show you the part which causes the error.

```
tdays.add(total);

Double a = tdays.get(ti); // this tries to access index 1, but there is only one element
Double b = tdays.get(ti - 1);
if (a > b) {
    big = tdays.get(ti);
    tday = ti;
}
```